# How to make custom tracker of horizontal progessbar of listview?

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, scrollbar

How can I make a custom tracker for listview in android? The tracker should auto visible when I scroll the listview horizontally and must be editable. I mean that I can set a text value to a textview inside the tracker as below image:

[image]      [image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this blog post http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=556 and the following framework https://github.com/rno/Android-ScrollBarPanel for your own use.

You can set the tooltip to a custom layout file with the above. You may have to do some adjustments for edge cases in the framework code since it allows rendering for  -ve coords and more then the screen height coords.